# Unable to get computed propery working with NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, computed-properties

I would like to subclass from `NSManagedObject` since I have lots of fields in my entity.

At the beginning I've created this:

```
class RecordModel: NSManagedObject {

    //  MARK: - Variables
    class var coreDataEntityName: String {
        return "Record"
    }
    /// Cover image of the song. Optional.
    var coverImage: UIImage? {
        set (image) {
            if image != nil {
                if let coverImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coverImage!) {
                    setValue(coverImageData, forKeyPath: "coverImageData")
                }
            }
        }
        get  {
            let coverImageData = value(forKeyPath: "coverImageData") as? Data
            if coverImageData != nil {
                return UIImage(data: coverImageData!)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    /**
     Initializes record with image object.
    */
    init(image: UIImage?) {
        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.managedContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: RecordModel.coreDataEntityName, in: context)!
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        self.coverImage = image
    }

}
```

And I get `EXT_BAD_ACCESS` error on self.coverImage = image.

What I wanted to achieve with my `coverImage` property is to cover `value` and `setValue` methods with it for more convenience.

If I step in debugger onto that line and perform

```
e setValue(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!), forKeyPath: "coverImageData")
```

which is basically what my custom setter does, I get no runtime errors.

It looks like I completely don't understand computed properties. Please help.

**EDIT:**

I've tried this as well:

```
var coverImage: UIImage? {
    set (image) {
        if image != nil {
            coverImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
        }
    }
    get  {
        if coverImageData != nil {
            return UIImage(data: coverImageData!)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
@NSManaged var coverImageData: Data?
```

Get code 2 now. Looks like an infinite loop is being executed for some reason.

Comment: Why `forKeyPath`? There is no key path. And actually dot notation like `self.coverImageData  = coverImageData` is *for more convenience* than the generic KVC methods.

Comment: @vadian The problem with this particular case is that I need `UIImage` object instead of `Data`. So I've decided to the conversion in getter and setter.

Comment: Yes, I know. But there is obviously a `@NSManaged` property `coverImageData` so dot notation is preferable over the KVC methods.

Comment: @vadian No, there's no such property. Writing `self.coverImageData = nil` gives me `Value of type 'RecordModel' has no member 'coverImageData'`.

Comment: Then I don't understand what is the purpose of the `coverImageData` key. `setValue:forKey:` implies that there is a stored or NSManaged property `coverImageData`.

Comment: @vadian `UIImage` can't be stored in Core Data entity. But `Data` can be.

Comment: Yes, of course, but there must be a `Data` attribute in the Core Data model which is usually represented by an `@NSManaged` property in the `NSManagedObject` subclass. I guess there is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @vadian I've edited the question to address this suspicion. The result is still negative.

Comment: The edited code looks OK and is supposed to work. I'm using a lot of similar computed properties in Core Data.